# Proper way to poll RSSI through hci_read_rssi()

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I am trying to poll the RSSI value of a bluetooth connection between 2 devices ( an Android phone and a chip ) periodically.

I used NDK to access the BlueZ library to use

```
hci_read_rssi(int dd, uint16_t handle, int8_t *rssi, int to)
```

The problem I don't know how to use it in term of passing the right parameters.
What is the proper way to use the function ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably different for you, but in the Bluetopia stack, in my `GAP_LE_Event_Callback` function, when I receive a Connection_Complete (GAP connection that is) I do this

```
     case etLE_Connection_Complete:
        ... 
        Word_t Connection_Handle;
        if ( GAP_LE_Query_Connection_Handle(BluetoothStackID, x->Peer_Address,
              &Connection_Handle) == 0) {

            Word_t Connection_HandleResult;
            SByte_t RSSIResult;
            Byte_t StatusResult;

            if (HCI_Read_RSSI(BluetoothStackID,Connection_Handle, &StatusResult,
                &Connection_HandleResult, &RSSIResult) == 0) {
                Display(("RSSI: %x %x %d\r\n",StatusResult,
                       Connection_HandleResult,RSSIResult));
```

If that doesn't work, then you need to a create a ConnectionHandle manually, with a new connection by calling `HCI_LE_Create_Connection`